# First installation by Activity: how to destroy that?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have to implement an activity to catch the preferences just after the installation of app.
This activity must showing only one time, the first time.

In the Manifest I have this:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.Setting"
        android:label="@string/settings_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But I have to destroy that after installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make a *StartActivity* which reads the preferences and decides which Activity to show first:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent i = null;
        // If the user is running the app for the first time
        if(getSharedPreferences("FirstRunCheck", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("is_first_run", true)) {
            // Set the target activity to settinga
            i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        }
        else {
            // Set the target activity to your main screen
            i = new Intent(this, MainScreenActivity.class);
        }
        // Start the activity
        startActivity(i);
        // Close the StartActivity
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have to use the settingsactivity only one time.. (after installation time)

Comment: Ah, maybe your "SettingsActivity" should be an "InstallationActivity", right?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Just set `is_first_run` to false and `SettingsActivity` (or `InstallationActivity`) will never be shown again

Comment: but I have a keyboard now that is set on MAIN, if I set another activity, is there a problem?

Comment: Your MAIN intent should always be StartActivity. Any other activity which needs started should do so inside the `onCreate`

Comment: ok, now it's ok with  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /

Comment: Yep, StartActivity should have both MAIN and LAUNCHER intents

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
          try
          {
                //in first run app go to catch and other go to try only
                SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
        String x= pref.getString("login", null);
        edit.commit();
                if(x.equals("first"))
                { 
                   //add your code here
                }
          }
          catch(Exception e)
      {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
        edit.putString("login","first");
        edit.commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), First.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }

    }
```